# Using WS-Security tools to secure web applications created by the Ruby on Rails framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

Is it possible for a web application developed using the Ruby on Rails framework to intercept all calls to it with a third party security tool? Any call to this web application goes to security tool instead of web application itself and then security tool can redirect it to web application.

Similar on the response side, web application responses are intercepted by security tool before send it to client (browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use befor_methods to do this if i understand what you want to do correctly

Callbacks are hooks into the life cycle of an Active Record object that allow you to trigger logic before or after an alteration of the object state. This can be used to make sure that associated and dependent objects are deleted when destroy is called (by overwriting before_destroy) or to massage attributes before they're validated (by overwriting before_validation). As an example of the callbacks initiated, consider the Base#save call for a new record:

```
(-) save

(-) valid

(1) before_validation

(-) validate

(2) after_validation

(3) before_save

(4) before_create

(-) create

(5) after_create

(6) after_save

(7) after_commit
```

Also, an after_rollback callback can be configured to be triggered whenever a rollback is issued. Check out ActiveRecord::Transactions for more details about after_commit and after_rollback.

Additionally, an after_touch callback is triggered whenever an object is touched.

Lastly an after_find and after_initialize callback is triggered for each object that is found and instantiated by a finder, with after_initialize being triggered after new objects are instantiated as well.

There are nineteen callbacks in total, which give you immense power to react and prepare for each state in the Active Record life cycle. The sequence for calling Base#save for an existing record is similar, except that each _create callback is replaced by the corresponding _update callback.

**Examples:**

```
class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Strip everything but digits, so the user can specify "555 234 34" or
  # "5552-3434" and both will mean "55523434"
  before_validation(on: :create) do
    self.number = number.gsub(/[^0-9]/, "") if attribute_present?("number")
  end
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :record_signup

  private
    def record_signup
      self.signed_up_on = Date.today
    end
end

class Firm < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Destroys the associated clients and people when the firm is destroyed
  before_destroy { |record| Person.destroy_all "firm_id = #{record.id}"   }
  before_destroy { |record| Client.destroy_all "client_of = #{record.id}" }
end
```